# Aws s3 403 forbidden on some of my img files

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed my testing/first app on the aws s3 and I have a problem with some of the images being loaded. Some of the images are loading normally but some of them are getting 403 forbidden error. I'm running there nginx server. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Please post the url and the bucket policy.

Comment: I solved it. There was an permission problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: Could you answer your own question with the solution attached? Thank you.

Comment: Cool dude.Yeah I will.

Comment: @jellycsc can you also give me an upvote ? :D

Comment: Sure thing, upvoted ◡̈

Comment: Thank you my internet friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit. So I was able to fix this issue. Problem was in the permissions of the file see screens below.

before :[image]

after :[image]